# JWPlayer SDK supports ads in isolation?

Tags: android, ios, video-playback

I have an app that plays 10 videos. The first 4 are YouTube (YT) videos, the next 2 videos are my own videos (MY) hosted on my server, the next 4 are YouTube videos.

To illustrate:
YT, YT, YT, YT, MY, MY, YT, YT, YT, YT.

Now, the app has a single video section, but YT videos are played by the YouTube official player and my videos are played by the default iOS AVplayer. So essentially, I use 2 players that constantly replace each other in the app - in other words I have a "universal player" because it decides what underlying player should be used based on the content.

Now, I want to play a single ad. Is it possible to use JWPlayer to insert an ad between the 2 "MY" videos? I want to continue using my existing AVplayer player, but just introduce ads through JW independently. So essentially, I see my "universal player" start embedding 3 players - YouTube, AVplayer, and JWPlayer (used only to insert the ads).

Can one use JWPlayer in this way - ie Let the ads play in JWPlayer, but Jw doesn't know what videos precede or follow the ad.

Thanks